# Consume information from multiple windows services

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, monitoring, nettcpbinding

**HOW TO CONSUME INFORMATION FROM MULTIPLE WINDOWS SERVICE **

- I have a central Administrator machine  and 40 other acts like clients , and what i need to do **:**
   
  **1-** install a windows service in each client's machine to get their information*

  - : IP Address
  - : Mac Address
  - : Host Name
  - : Upload Rate(for internet connection)
  - : Download Rate(for internet connection)

  **2-** the Ability to :

  - :Cut the connection
  - :limit the bandwidth

---

**PS :** This is my last year project so it's very important to solve it , thinks

---

**What i did :**

```
 public string         addip ()           
         {
             var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
             string x =(from addr in hostEntry.AddressList where addr.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork" select addr.ToString()).FirstOrDefault() ;

             return x; 
         }
    public string         hostname ()        
          {
             string x = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() ;

             return x;  
          }
    public string         downlo ()          
          {
              List<NetworkInterface> nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(network => network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet).ToList();
              NetworkInterface nic = nics[0];
              IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = nic.GetIPv4Statistics();
              int bytesReceivedSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesReceived - double.Parse(BytesReceived)) / 1024;
              BytesReceived = interfaceStats.BytesReceived.ToString();
              string x = (bytesReceivedSpeed.ToString() + " KB/s") ;

           return x;   
         }
    public string         uplo ()            
      {
              List<NetworkInterface> nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(network => network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet).ToList();
              NetworkInterface nic = nics[0];
              IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = nic.GetIPv4Statistics();
              int bytesSentSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesSent - double.Parse(BytesSent)) / 1024;
              BytesSent = interfaceStats.BytesSent.ToString();
              string x = (bytesSentSpeed.ToString()+ " KB/s") ;

              return x;  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to take à look at this link → https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol

Is this a monitoring application??
If so, why you don't just code your app based on an open source project (Nagios Core for example, which is based on C → http://www.nagios.org/download/core/thanks?t=1364211633)

Good luck

Comment: Nope ! i need to do it my self ! with wcf , nettcpbiding and it is a monitoring application , and don't forget that i need to do actions .... so a need a custom application ( this is my last year project )

Answer (score 0):

Still a significant question.
If it were me doing this.

- I'd create a windows service.
- Add a listening port, you'll need to pick one.
- Set up it up receive and to commands, GetData, GetIP, CutConnection
  etc.
- Maybe a UDP port as well so it can respond to an anybody there
  broadcast.
- You'll need to come up with command phrases,
- And responses. Personally I'd make that generic, say an xml snippet.

  Then I'd write a noddy app to prove that out. And try it out on
  selection of your 40 machines, different windows versions, different
  parts of the network etc. Then I'd start working on the Monitor /
  controller.

Attack it in bits, add on functionality. Shouldn't be that hard this, try and name your objects properly though. I know the academic types don't give a stuff, but you will when you try to this and get lost on whether downlo, gets the speed, responds to a getspeed message, sends a getspeed message and waits for a response. Gets them to display in the UI...

What order you attack this in is up to you.
But learn it bit by bit. 
Just knock up a do nothing windows service. 
Do a peer to peer chat app to play with WCF. 
Write a little command parser.

If it was me first thing I'd do would be a client send out a UDP broadcast, and another to respond to it, and then build up a list of machines with the responder app on it. Then I'd turn ther latter into a service, but the main point is build working modules, then join them together. Don't join together a flaky mish-mash of misnamed obscure functions and then try to get it working.

Keep it simple to start with. For instance you could use threading and parallelisation. Tip get it working first.
You don't need WCF or a service to do this.
It would be crap. But a little exe on the kicked off by the scheduler, that reads and writes to a share, would do the job.

Build modules, prove them. Write noddy services and apps, just building up a list of machines, that respond to a message on a port will teach you a lot.

Comment: what i did i a windows service that provide with information i need , and i client who collect those information , but how can i handle multiple windows service ? here we go back to the main question ! , who is the host and the client ( in wcf ) because in the peer to peer chat applications that i'v found , we place a separated host that open the service , then communication is done between client .. will i do the same thing ?

Comment: UDP Broadcast is what you want to look at. You client shouts "anybody there"? Each "service" responds with yes I'm here. That gives you an IP, you add that to your list of machines with my service app on and then talk to them individually.